# How do I solve the inequality $x^2(y-1) <0$

Tags: inequality

I need help solving this inequality : $x^2(y-1)<0$. I do not have a first step in solving this inequality.

Comment: Do cases and draw a number line

Comment: I assume you are reffering to real numbers. We have $x^2 \geq 0$ for every number in $\mathbb{R}$, which leaves only one option.

$$y-1 \leq 0$$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $x^2 \ge 0$ for all real $x$. So then all you need is when $y-1 < 0$ (i.e. when $y-1$ is negative). When does this happen?

Comment: Change it $y - 1 \leq 0$. ;)

Comment: No its suppose to be less than not less than or equal to.

Comment: @Stefan4024 Thanks even though I accidentally had it right at first. MathJax isn't rendering for me so I am having a hard time reading stuff on the site.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2\geq0$ for all real $x$, hence we must have $y-1<0$. Therefore the solutions are

$$x<0,y<1$$
and
$$x>0,y<1$$

to be precise.